# Malaysian enTRI visa approved but changes of hotel

Tags: visas, malaysia, proof-of-accommodation

I will be travelling to Kuala Lumpur for three days, my entri visa got approved and I wanted to change the hotel from the one I provided as an accommodation in visa. Will there be any conflict if I change the hotel and have the prove of the new hotel instead?

Answer (score 1):

The immigration will gladly accept the new hotel. Immigration official only cares whether you have a valid proof of accommodation. It doesn't have to be exactly provided.

In much of the cases, they only ask for return ticket.

For official rule - https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/FAQ/PDF/FAQ/Support/FAQ_eNTRi_Indian_en.pdf?version=1.3

Page4, second question